# ES6 — How to destructure from an object with a string key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object

```
{
  hello_en: 'hello world',
  'hello_zh-CN': '世界您好',
  something: 'nice day',
  something_else: 'isn\'t it'
}
```

being passed into a function

```
function(data) {
  const { hello_en, hello_zh-CN, ...rest } = data
  // do some stuff with hello_en and hello_zh-CN
  // so some other stuff with rest
}
```

but of course `hello_zh-CN` is not a valid key name.

I am unable to write

```
const { hello_en, 'hello_zh-CN', ...rest } = data
```

as that gives an error.

How can I destructure an object's properties when one of the keys is a string?

Comment: See this [MDN section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Invalid_JavaScript_identifier_as_a_property_name)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Destructure it by providing a valid key name like

```
  const { hello_en, 'hello_zh-CN': hello_zHCN, ...rest } = data
```

Working snippet

```js
var data = {
  hello_en: 'hello world',
  'hello_zh-CN': '世界您好',
  something: 'nice day',
  something_else: 'isn\'t it'
}

const { hello_en, 'hello_zh-CN': hello_zHCN, ...rest } = data

console.log(hello_zHCN);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The answer seems so obvious once it's in front of me. :-)

Comment: Yes, its looks like it, but its not, I have stuck with this myself for a long time too :)

Comment: Extending topic starters' questions - is there a way to specify destructuring alias via text constant or any other way? For example, `const {'_abc_abc_': someAliasConstant} = someObject;`