# Destructuring an object from a dynamic string name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I got this config.json file :

```
"signs_table": {
  "id_field": "dummy_id_field_name",
  "prop" : "dummy_prop_name"
   ...
}
```

This file contains tons of configuration for huge amount of tables stored in a database. Every table has different field name but the configuration for my code is the same for each table (an Id field name, different property fields, but of course fields name changes from table to table).

So, in my code, I am getting a data object and I want to be able to destructs it to dynamically named properties (from the configuration) like so :

```js
const { dummy_id_field_name, dummy_prop_name} = this.props.data
```

but this is hard coded way. I would like to load the named properties based on the configuration file.
something like :

```js
const IdField = config.get("signs_table").id_field // this will retrieve the actual field name from config.json I want to be able to pass it through the destructuring operation
const PropField = config.get("signs_table").prop
const { IdField , PropField } = data
```

Here the `config.get("signs_table")` line is a from a class method that manage my config.json file...it basically retrieves the property.

So far I found this usefull approach :
[ES6 — How to destructure from an object with a string key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343763/es6-how-to-destructure-from-an-object-with-a-string-key)

But this does not help me since I need to first retrieve the field name from the configuration file...

Any Idea ?

Comment: Your destructuring will not work anyway, because your object has no properties `dummy_id_field_name`. Shouldn't you be doing `const { id_field, prop } = this.props.data` instead?

Comment: why do you destructure at all - what are you going to do with the values later?

Comment: @thedude : I will use them for a common data process for all the tables....

Comment: @Terry : This will not work....this is all my question about. How can I pass the `id_field` which is a key in my `config.json` file to be read as its value in the destructuring

Comment: can you show a sample usage?

Comment: @thedude : actually the answers were very helpfull. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid fetching the field names from the config files first:

```
const { id_field: IdField, pro: PropField } = config.get("signs_table"); // this will retrieve the actual field names from config.json
```

Then, afterwards you can use those as computed property names when destructuring your actual data:

```
const { [IdField]: idValue , [PropField]: propValue } = this.props.data;
console.log(idValue, propValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can de-structure arbitrary property names as I'll show below, but the question is why are you forcing yourself into a syntax you are unfamiliar with.  You should stick with the readable and straightforward approach instead of some fancy convoluted method.

```js
const idField = config.get("signs_table").id_field; // this will retrieve the actual field name from config.json I want to be able to pass it through the destructuring operation
const propField = config.get("signs_table").prop;
const { [idField]: idValue, [propField]: propValue } = data;
```

It would be more straightforward to simply avoid the de-structuring altogether and access the fields directly.

```js
const idField = config.get("signs_table").id_field; // this will retrieve the actual field name from config.json I want to be able to pass it through the destructuring operation
const propField = config.get("signs_table").prop;

const idValue = data[idField];
const propValue = data[propField];
```